# How to have double line spacing everywhere except tables?

Tags: tables, spacing

I want doublespacing **everywhere** except tables. There is already an [identical question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156078/double-line-spacing-except-in-tables), but the MWE had no footnotes. In fact, the chosen solution **does not work** for footnotes. They remain still single spaced (see MWE at bottom).

My MWE has footnotes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \caption{table}
        \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
            1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 0 \\
            1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 0 \\
            1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 0 \\
            1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 0 \\
            1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 0                                   
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using the `setspace` package, as in the linked answer and in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258688/how-to-remove-double-spacing-in-table-cell-wrap), but it doesn't enforce doublespacing in the footnotes, as said earlier. Below is the MWE to confirm this. As can be seen, `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` doesn't fix that either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\longtable{\par\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]

  Test.\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

  \begin{longtable}{lp{10cm}}
    1&a\tabularnewline
    2&b\tabularnewline
    3&\lipsum[2]
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how we can truly force doublespacing **everywhere** but tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, just a quick fix for the footnotes, taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62672/170958):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\longtable{\par\singlespacing}

% added these three lines
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]

  Test.\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

  \begin{longtable}{lp{10cm}}
    1&a\tabularnewline
    2&b\tabularnewline
    3&\lipsum[2]
  \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the other answer and also answers mine.